# Generate a white cylinder

Tags: geometry

I need to create a ring with some thickness.  To do that I think to built two-cylinder and superpose them

```
Cyl1 = Graphics3D[{ Black, 
Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.1}, {0, 0, 0.1}}, 195]}, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1}];

 Cyl2 = Graphics3D[{White, Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 50]}, 
   ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1}];
```

I have a problem with Cyl2. I get a pink cylinder, not white.  How can I change the color of the cylinder?

thanks

Comment: use the option `Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}`?

Comment: Thanks so much!!

Comment: You can also use Glow; 
Graphics3D[{Glow[White], Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 50]}, 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1}]. 
It produces the same result as the suggestion by @kglr

Answer (score 2):

If your main objective is to create a black ring you can do this:

```
c1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.1}, {0, 0, 0.1}}, 195];
c2 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 50];
r = RegionDifference[c1, c2];
rp = Graphics[RegionPlot3D[r, PlotPoints -> 50, Lighting -> {{"Directional", Black}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make a 2D ring with `Annulus` and extrude with `RegionProduct`. Then draw a white cylindrical graphic with `RegionPlot3D`. The pink color is caused by default lighting. Use `Lighting -> "Neutral"` for white light sources in default positions.

```
r = RegionProduct[Annulus[{0, 0}, {rInner, rOuter}], 
   Line[{{-thickness/2}, {thickness/2}}]] /. {rInner -> 50, 
   rOuter -> 195, thickness -> 2/10}

Graphics[RegionPlot3D[r, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotStyle -> White, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Background -> LightBlue]]
```

[image: 3D extruded annulus]

```
Volume[r]
```

> 7105 π